# How to bake in EEVEE? Cycles baked texture is atrocious!

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, materials, texture-baking, eevee-render-engine

BTW: I am a complete noob in Blender, sorry if this is a silly question!

From what I've found, it seems you can only bake in Cycles. Does anyone know of a way to bake materials in Eevee? When I baked in cycles, the output texture was very low quality, and had a lot of noise and blurriness. It also had strange edge glitches :C (See last image) 
[image]
CYCLES

EEVEE
   [image]

[image]
Comparison between Eevee render & Cycles Baked Texture

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set more samples for less noise.
Set identation in uv map than you remove the seams, if you need only colors select in the bake menu "diffuse" and deselect all checkbox except "color"